# jQuery show div if value > x

Tags: jquery-selectors, if-statement, html

I've been reading lots of topics about jQuery and showing div's, but I haven't found the answer to my specific question yet. Here's the thing:

Based on my  value I want to show either div A or div B. The select field is filled with 20 countries, of which 19 get the same div (B) and only one get's another div (A). The one that get's div A has "value=1", so I figured to apply a "if select value > 1, show div B" principle. However, I can't manage to get it working. My other select-show-div mechanism was based on the exact value (I've posted it below), but this if-else thing makes me going crazy.

Any help would be appreciated!

My old value=exact code:

```
$('.div').hide();
$('#country').change(function() {
   $('.div').hide();
   $('#country' + $(this).val()).show();
   });
});
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<div id="country1" class="div">
 BLABLA
</div>

<div id="country2" class="div">
 BLABLA
</div>

etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand if you have a select menu, or divs. A possible solution could be the following:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var countryVal = $("select option:selected").val(); //get the value of the selected
    $("#country1, #country2").hide(); //hide country divs, of previous selection
    if(countryVal == 1) {$("#country1").show();} else {$("#country2").show()}; //if countryVal is 1 (the diffrent value) show the div #country1 else show the div #country2
});
```

**updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YnYxD/1

Comment: Great piece of code Sotiris, that essentially fixes my problem! I have a select, which in turn triggers the div's. I've updated the fiddle to show my way of using it, but your code is plain awesomeness. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnYxD/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, all the others countries have a value > 1, so you can't simply use the value to generate the id. The id must be 1 if the value is 1 and 2 otherwise.

Try :

```
$('#country').change(function() {
   $('.div').hide();
   var id = $(this).val() == 1 ? 1 : 2;
   $('#country' + id).show();
   });
});
```